# «На короткой ноге» — почему так говорят?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Быть с кем-то запанибрата, общаться близко — быть с кем-то на **короткой ноге**.
Интересно было бы узнать, откуда пошло это выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Быть на короткой ноге" скопировано с французского *etre sur un bon pied* – буквально "быть на хорошей ноге". Иногда встречается поэтому и *на дружеской ноге*, это отсюда же. Например у Гоголя:

> Вы, может быть, думаете, что я только переписываю; нет, начальник отделения со мной на дружеской ноге. Этак ударит по плечу: "Приходи, братец, обедать!".

Из "хорошей" в "короткую" нога превратилась благодаря переносному значению последнего прилагательного. Короткий – значит "близкий, доверительный", накоротке – "в близких, дружеских отношениях".

Comment: Да, но при чем тут нога?))

Comment: @fuchoin-kazuki Возможно, дело в неверном переводе французского pied, которое также означает "основание", "подножие", "фундамент".

Answer (score 0):

Слова "нога" употребляется здесь в значении "шаг". "Быть на короткой ноге" (т.е. на коротком шаге) означает наличие близких, доверительных отношений, лёгкость доступа. Обычно применяется в отношении людей, занимающих высокое социальное или административное положение.